# How to use right hand gesture in kinect v2?

Tags: wpf, kinect, right-click

I am using kinect (V2) for developing a gesture based application in WPF. I am able to scroll the image, zoom it, get the click event. Now what i need  to do is use the  right click gesture using kinect. What is the gesture to use right click using kinect or do i need to write any custom code to achieve it. I need to use the right click using gesture in kinect ? Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a gestural system is not the same of implementing a WIMP (Windows-Icons-Menu-Pointer) interface. So you should probably completely overcome the idea of interacting with a desktop and "use a mouse via gestures". If you will decide to follow this latter (wrong) idea, you will risk to produce a not-so-usable interface.

Anyway, there is no standard "right-click gesture", and this is due to the fact that a gestural interface is different from a classical desktop GUI.

You should write some custom gesture to do this indeed.

For more information, take a look to the [Human Interface Guidelines 2.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/6/676611B4-1982-47A4-A42E-4CF84E1095A8/KinectHIG.2.0.pdf) by Microsoft.